# Show me a working example of an Xcode 7.2.1 Workspace with Upsurge Playground?

Tags: xcode, cocoapods, swift-playground, upsurge

I have burned a day trying to get the example Playground that comes with [Upsurge](https://github.com/aleph7/Upsurge) working with Xcode 7.2.1. I have tried every hint I was able to find here on *Stackoverlow* already.

The code from the Playground works just fine if I move it, for example, into the iOS app delegate. But in the Playground, Upsurge's operators and functions are not being resolved despite the module `Upsurge` apparently importing correctly.

[image: Errors in Playground]

The `sum` function does of course exist and has a passing unit test case.

[image: Passing Unit Test]

I am stumped. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested their Playground and it doesn't work for me either - it looks like the files are faulty (there's a one month old commit stating "Fix corrupt playground files" but it doesn't look like it was successfull...).

---

But there's a workaround: you can create a brand new Upsurge Playground then paste their code in it.

To create a Playground with Pods there's known techniques, well explained on SO - but I suggest a quick way: using the "cocoapods-playground" Gem.

Update Cocoapods itself with `gem update cocoapods` then install this new utility with `gem install cocoapods-playgrounds`.

You can then use it to create a working Upsurge Playground with `pod playgrounds Upsurge`.

Once generated the Playground will automatically open: build once, paste the code and you're good to go (you have to disable "Editor > Show rendered markup" in theirs to be able to copy the code - or you can copy it from the repository).

[image]